# Strange microtype behaviour

Tags: spacing, microtype, frenchspacing

I am trying to use the [microtype](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package as illustrated in this page:
http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/pdflatex-microtype/.

But I am getting this output instead:

[image: faulty output]

So any ideas why this is happening?

Here is the code as requested:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3.7cm}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

EDIT1: I just realize that there are some small literal differences between the `blindtext` output that I got and the blog's one. For example instead of `what` in the third line, there is a `how`. I am going to change my `blindtext` to match the blog's copy to see if there is some improvement.

EDIT2: Here are the result after I enabled `\frenchspacing` and made the `blindtext` corrections. Note that in the blog's example the "`a`" should be one line above its current position.

[image: updated faulty output]

EDIT3: I updated my `microtype` package to version `2.5 beta-07` but I got no drastic changes.

Comment: With `\textls[-9]{\blindtext}` you will get it away. But then later you will get more white space. For such narrow columns it is always better to use `\raggedright` (or for special cases `\raggedleft`) – and much, much better to load the package `ragged2e` and use then `\RaggedRight` (or `\RaggedLeft`).

Comment: I get the same output as in the blog. Which version of `microtype` do you use? Is there any warning in the `.log` file? Finally, which version of `pdflatex` are you using?

Comment: @mafp I am using `pdflatex` version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 and `microtype` version 2.4.

I am not sure (since i just started to use Latex) but I didn't notice anything unnusual in the `.log` file

Comment: I use `microtype-2.5-beta07`, but since you have a different text, this probably is the reason.

Comment: The default LaTeX behaviour is that it _doubles_ the spacing after a period. This is what's causing the large spacing. If you enable `\frenchspacing` LaTeX will insert a normal space after the period. When I enabled `\frenchspacing` and compiled your example it solved the probelm.

Comment: @mafp as Marc suggested I enabled `\frenchspacing` and I changed the text so they would match. While my document now is much more similar to the blog's one, there are some minor differences and one `underfull` warnings which didn't appear before

Comment: And what happens when using the updated text, and no `\frenchspacing`?

Comment: There are small differences, but the huge white space I marked still remains.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me that there is an error on the blog and the original run done when the screen capture was taken was at a slightly wider `minipage`, possibly at 3.9cm or the microtype defaults file is different.

For very narrow columns, you are normally better off with the `ragged2e` package. Compare with this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3.4cm}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the same output as in the blog, so something different is going on here.

Comment: @mafp As mentioned, possibly the version of the defaults file.